# Android app crashes when I add a button to the layout xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

So I have been having this issues for two days now and don't know why this is happening. 
When I try to update the layout xml file for a activity by just adding a button it crashes the class. When I delete the button it works fine. The button doesn't even have to do anything just be there and it will crash.

So by adding this to the xml layout file it causes it to break

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/Test"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: where you adding that code above "account" Button or elsewhere

Comment: bellow the logout button in the userInfo RelativeLayout holder

Comment: the problem is one of findViewById methods . one of ids is set wrong . the problem comes from line 70 in CustomerPage class

Comment: historyListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.history); But this is pointing the a listview where I want it to point to I think. How is it wrong?

Comment: I tried to emulate your code using Android Studio and managed to run it properly.. The ***Test Button*** is appearing below the ***Customer Name*** TextView.. was that your intended display? or was the Test Button supposed to go below Logout Button and above the Account Button?

Comment: I was just trying to get it to display anywhere on the app with out crashing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone I figured out what was wrong with this stupid thing.
Ok so apparently all I needed to do is rename the Listview and then clean the project twice and it worked.

After some running around I found out the Android studio has issues with keeping old names of items in it. so the best way is to clean the project and if that doesn't work rename the variables and re-clean the project.

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself, but my answer is still valid so can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that your code is fine, you should try these steps:

1. Clean project - **Build -> Clean Project**
2. Invalidate caches - **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**
3. Disable Instant Run - **Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment
   -> Instant Run -> uncheck Enable Instant Run ...**